# I'm looking for to generate access token using azure credentials in c#

Tags: c#, azure

I'm looking for to generate access token using azure credentials in c#. This is my code but its not working.With this i'm facing Unexpected character '<' error.

```
        var uri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
        {
            ["grant_type"] = "password",
            ["client_id"] ="Azure client id"
            ["username"] = "CRM User name",
            ["password"] = "CRM Passowrd",
            ["client_secret"] ="Azure Client app scret"
            ["resource"] = "Your CRM Url",
        };
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters.UrlEncode());

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = body.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Token));
            return serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Token;
        }
```

Comment: Test this with something like POSTman - you are probably getting back some html hence the '<' character and probably a 404 html error message you are trying ti serialze.

Comment: @Shane_Yo I tried with POSTMAN but in that I'm getting error like this : AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '7bfdcd13-7830-4a50-b6d9-76289f156a7a' was not found in the directory 'microsoft.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 94704759-0281-45b3-a85a-38f05139d700\r\nCorrelation ID: 2e60107e-3dee-43ca-8ad5-25456509534f\r\nTimestamp: 2020-10-26 07:18:55Z",

Comment: You should maybe give more details or screenshots of your app registration and how you are calling it again in postman (you can blur your security sensitive data), The above error shows that you are possibly calling the wrong resource or wrong details to oauth2/token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how a crm token is retreived using postman < you can applythis in your c# code. but get this right first:

[image: Postman token call]

also make sure that Azure Active directory > application has the above reply url and dynamics security assigned (api permissions).
[image: Api permissions]

Comment: see if "granting admin consent.." in the above screen helps.

Comment: @sreeman Please accept the suggestion as an answer, if this worked for you. It will help others in community.

Comment: @Shane_Yo What will be the client_id and client_secret? because for the tenant, I have the only tenantid, and we are using username and password, so client_id cannot be my username Guid. Where from you got the client_id and client_secret?

Comment: @Shane_Yo I have permissions on three service principals, I have used client id and client secret from one of them, and I run the code, I got the error Invoke-RestMethod : {"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "AADSTS50056: Invalid or missing password: password does not exist in the directory for this 
user.

Comment: if your grant_type is password you need to supply normal username and password, for principle clientid and secret (you need to create an accplication in Ad to create the clientid and secret) <- then use grant_type : client_credentials (with only client_id and client_secret)

example :
Request Body
grant_type: "client_credentials"
client_id: "0000000f-babe-babe-babe-00000000acde"
client_secret: "PKcs.~vY8_1323bbaaXXX-XXX_S.WQ8GRM"